# IHTMLElement to HWnd

Tags: c++, html

Is it possible to get a window handle out of IHTMLElement?
If so, can someone show me how to do it in c++?

TIA

Comment: Why do you think that there is a unique HWND for an IHTMLElement?

Comment: I do not say the handle is unique. I just need to know a way to retrieve a handle out of IHTMLElement.

Comment: For what purpose, though?  Why do you need an element's `HWND`? All aspects of an element's properties and behavior are accessible via the browser's DOM instead. Besides, browsers are free to hide their element windows from the outside world, assuming any child windows are even used at all. Try using Spy++ or similar tool to spy IE's main window sometime - you won't see any accessible child windows used by elements!

Comment: I don't think there is any hope although I have the same kind of demand. Window handle is a Windows concept which doesn't exist in HTML standard.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau - TeamB It would be much easier to integrate various web auto testing tools if every html element has its unique identifier. I can retrieve the **handle** of a link using Watir by XPath, and pass it to QTP to click on.

Comment: HTML elements are not windows. The only HWND that exists is for the parent content window.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably possible if three things are true:

1) you have a specific browser instance which you are firing up using C++ / C#, 
2) obviously, you must be in a Windows environment, and
3) the IHTMLElement happens to be a type which is rendered as a separate control (such as an IFrame, potentially, or a SELECT item, etc.)

You will not, however, be able to find the `hWnd` of an element such as a `<div>`, `<span>`, etc. - because those items are not rendered as separate windows controls. They are painted onto the browser's canvas by the browser's rendering engine.